# NMEA-2000 Message 129540 ("GNSS Sats in View"): SNR field is integer or decimal?

Tags: gps, nmea

If you're familiar with the older [NMEA 0183](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_0183), there was a "GSV" record for reporting information about GPS satellites in view, including their SNR (signal-to-noise ratio, also known as carrier-to-noise-density ratio, C/N0), though only as an integer value (between 0 and 99, nominally in decibels, often in dB-Hz). [a](http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/#gsv),[b](http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm#GSV),[c](http://hemispheregnss.com/gpsreference/GPGSV.htm)

Did this situation change in the newer [NMEA 2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_2000)?  There is a similar message 129540 about "GNSS Sats in View", but the free [N2K Field Descriptions](http://www.nmea.org/Assets/july%202010%20nmea2000_v1-301_app_b_pgn_field_list.pdf) does not specify the fields data types:

> GNSS information on current satellites in view tagged by sequence ID.
>   Information includes PRN, elevation, azimuth, SNR, defines the number
>   of satellites; defines the satellite number and the information.

I found an official [white paper](http://www.nmea.org/Assets/2000-explained-white-paper.pdf) which gives an example for a similar SNR field but for Loran stations instead of GPS satellites, which says:

> Data type: int16;  Range: +/-327.5 dB;  Resolution: 0.01 dB

Does anyone with knowledge of the specification confirm that what applies to message 130054 ("Loran-C Signal Data") is also applicable to message 129540 ("GNSS Sats in View")? Searching further I found some software documentation suggesting that it does:[docs](http://www.keversoft.com/downloads/packetlogger_20120415_explain.txt)

> PGN: 129540 - GNSS Sats in View (...)   Field #8: SNR
>                     Bits: 16
>                     Units: dB
>                     Resolution: 0.01
>                     Signed: false

So now the final question is: do real receivers make use of the extra resolution available?  Could anyone with access to a GPS/GNSS unit supporting NMEA 2000 provide a text sample of that message output, please? I heard that some of latest Garmins and Hemisphere receivers work that way.

I have a scientific application that requires SNR values more precise than 1 dB, see [Scientific Utility of the Signal-to-Noise Ratio (SNR) Reported by GPS Receivers](http://xenon.colorado.edu/Bilich_snrQuality.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gamin technical support has said:

> I can confirm that the 19x NMEA 2000 antenna does use the full 0.01dB
>   resolution in "GNSS Sats in View" mode.